parseStrict() vs parseLenient() DateTimeFormatterBuilder java
Given:
String validInput = "2023-12-31";
String lenientInput = "2023-12-31  "; // Extra space

DateTimeFormatter strictFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
   .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
   .parseStrict()
   .toFormatter();

DateTimeFormatter lenientFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
  .parseLenient()
  .toFormatter();

LocalDate strictDate = LocalDate.parse(validInput, strictFormatter);
System.out.println("Strict: " + strictDate);   //OK WORKS

LocalDate lenientDate = LocalDate.parse(lenientInput, lenientFormatter);
System.out.println("Lenient: " + lenientDate); // but Failed 

I can not understand the exact differences between parseStrict() vs parseLenient().
I tried many patterns and found that 'lenient' v 'strict' appears to make no difference. What does parseLenient() do and what pattern can I use so that LocalDate.parse("2023-12-31    ", whatFormatterToUseHere) parses into Dec 31st 2023?
EDIT:-
DateTimeFormatterBuilder dfb=new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
dfb.parseLenient();
dfb.appendPattern("MMyydd");
String s="092430";
System.out.println(dfb.toFormatter().parse(s));

Why am I getting
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '092430' could not be parsed at index 6  


Use [code block] format for code. Also explain what didn't work.

@Chaosfire  you accidently moved System.out.println("Lenient: " + ... out of the code block - missing a space! Hint: it is better/easier to use three backticks ``` on a line to delimit code

The API is a bit unfortunate; the concept 'strict v lenient' occurs twice for two utterly unrelated concepts.
out of bounds leniency
One 'sense' of lenient is out of bounds values. The date '2024-02-30' does not exist. However, it parses fine: Parsing is done  segment by segment, and it's got a valid year (2024, perfectly valid year), a valid month (02, nothing wrong with that), and a valid date (30 is just fine. Sure, in context of 'oh we are in the year 2024 and the month 02' it makes no sense, but that's not what we're doing yet. We're just mapping characters onto fields here).
In strict mode, resolving those separate values into a single date fails because Feb 30th 2024 does not exist. In lenient mode, the resolver will fudge it and ends up producing a LocalDate that is either 2024-02-29 or 2024-03-01 (I'm not sure which one; if you care that's highly indicative you don't want lenient in this sense).
But that is not what parseLenient() does at all; to get that you use withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT).
Field parsing leniency
What parseLenient() is about is to be a bit more cavalier specifically in how to interpret some given input as a valid value for the field we're parsing. For example, is '02' a valid value when parsing MMM (given that MMM means: The month as text and 02 isn't textual?)
In your code snippet, you've misunderstood what parseLenient() does and you have misunderstood how to use it.
How it works
You call parseLenient() before you call appendPattern. It modifies all further append calls. parseStrict() does nothing at all (as strict is the default), except as a way to 'unset' lenient mode. You can do:
DateTimeFormatter lenientFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .parseLenient()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-")
  .parseStrict()
  .appendPattern("MM-dd")
  .toFormatter();

and this gets you a formatter that parses the year (and the dash that separates year from month) leniently, then month, day, and the dash that separates those strictly. Calling parseLenient() and then toFormatter() doesn't do anything.
What it does
It doesn't do what you think it does. Those trailing spaces are still invalid even if you move parseLenient() up so that it applies to your pattern.
In strict mode, if you configure the month part to be textual then when parsing the month has to be in textual form. In lenient mode its fine if its numeric instead.
DateTimeFormatter lenientFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .parseLenient()
  .parseCaseInsensitive()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")
  .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2024-Feb-20", lenientFormatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2024-02-20", lenientFormatter));
DateTimeFormatter strictFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .parseCaseInsensitive()
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd")
  .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2024-Feb-20", strictFormatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2024-02-20", strictFormatter));

Run the above code. The very last line is the only one that fails. Because it's in strict mode, and MMM indicates you want the textual month, not the numeric month. In lenient mode, that doesn't matter, in strict mode, it does, and 2024-02-20 fails to parse.
LocalDate.parse("2024-02-20   ", lenientFormatter) fails no matter how lenient you set it up. Best way to deal with that is simply to .trim() them off instead of trying to come up with a pattern that deals with it.
